# Running python script in a makefile target to generate source files in parallel

Tags: python, makefile, parallel-processing, dependencies

I have a makefile with one of the target being a python script that goes through n number of txt files and generates corresponding source files serially. I am trying to parallelize  this execution. Here is the makefile -

```
.PHONY: all
 all: target1 target2 target3

.PHONY: target1
target1: 
    ##recipe_target1

.PHONY: target2 
target2: target2_pyscript_dependency
    ##recipe_target2

.PHONY: target2_pyscript_dependency
target2_pyscript_dependency:
     python.exe *<some_python_script.py>* *<txt_files> <output_dir>*  
     ## execute this in parallel so the source files get generated in parallel

.PHONY: target3
target3:
    ##recipe_target3
```

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Do you know how to parallelize the script when running it from the command line, without Make? Do you know what the names of the names of the source files before you run the script? Is there a simple relationship like `foo.txt => foo.src`?

Comment: @Beta I'm not sure about how to parallelize running from the command line. The names of the txt files are known and all these txt files are in the <txt_files> folder. So yes the conversion is simple as foo.txt > foo.src.

Comment: I assume there is some crucial information missing here, otherwise you could simply do `%.src: %.txt; python <some_python_script.py> $@ > $^` and make would take care of parallel invocations of Python. Does the script need to be called with all input files in one invocation, together?

Comment: @Vroomfondel Yes the script does need the input files to be called together. However, when you say "make would take care of parallel invocations of Python", don't we need to usually specify if parallelism is required? Like say for example, make <target> -j<n>, where n is the no. of jobs to be run in parallel. This will tell the make file to execute parallelism. However -j doen't work with this particular python script target.

Comment: Yes, you must invoke parallelism by giving `-jn`, which however is trivial. OTOH parallelizing the work in your Python script is neither that nor in the responsibility of `make` - you will need to be more Python-centric in your question IMHO.